# Loop in django with 2 parameter

Tags: html, django, templates

I am new to `Django`, I have passed two list(`rawmaterial` and `food`) to my template, and then I want to have a loop like this :(it is the logic of my aim, the syntax is not correct)

```
for(i=0;i<food.length;i++)
   <div ,id="menuFood>
   <h4> food.name(i)</h4>
   <h4> rawmaterial.name(i)</h4>
   </div>
```

but when i searched, i can find only loop like this:

```
{% for o in some_list %}
{% endfor %}
```

so with this syntax , I can't understand how to create that loop. I think only nested loop can make by this syntax..

here is my view code :

```
    def foods(request):
    food = Food.objects.all()
    raw = [];
    .
    .
    .
    raw.append(warehouse)
    return render(request, 'polls/foods.html', {'food': food,'rawmaterial': raw})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do index on django template, but you could just put 2 lists together in your views.py using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
food = Food.objects.all()
raw = []
# ...
raw.append(warehouse)

result = zip(food, raw)
return render(request, 'polls/foods.html', {'result': result})
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for food, raw in result %}
<h4>{{ food }}</h4>
<h4>{{ raw }}</h4>
{% endfor %}
```

By the way, you seems to come from java/c++ background because in python people never do:

```
for(i=0; i<food.length; i++)
    print food[i]
```

instead, we do:

```
for i in food:
    print i
```

Django template is adopting the similar syntax, it makes writing a loop a lot easier.